# Backdrop-blur effect, creates "inset Shadow" Issue, during transition

Tags: html, css, blur, onblur

### Issue:

weirdly **when** i use `Backdrop-filter: blur(Xpx);` **during** transition as seen below, **somehow** *"inset Shadows"* appear from nowhere, until the transition end..

[image]

### Demonstration of the Issue On [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ge096ouv/5/)

### Specs:

- Chrome Version: 83
- OS: Windows 10

### Outro:

Any idea?
Thanks in Advance .. (:

## - [ Update 23/6/2020 ]:

**Finally** found [some kind of work-around](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLkBmV4yGJ4) for those who might need something **that specific**, **althought** that doesn't answer my issue yet, as it doesn't work with element in the background [...]

## - [ Update 1/7/2021 ]:

**Works fine on** Chrome Version: 91.0.4472.114

Comment: Doesn't do it on my screen, which browser are you using?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights **Chrome** *(Version: 83)*

Answer (score 1):

## Intro.

So, what your experiencing is nothing new, actually, this is how `backdrop-filter` style-rule works according to W3C*
Coupled with the transition style-rule and no background, that makes-up for what you're experiencing.

## Fix and code tips.

Before we begin, I'll let you know that I don't support you using `backdrop-filter` as support is scarce in it as we can see in a very trusted resource*
I would recommend you use `filter` rule instead, as it is supported more*

Now, to move-no to some code mistakes and the fix for your problem.:

```css
body{
background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d2/64/ce/d264ce996ff6531fe191dfce5b200b3a.jpg");
background-position: center; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color:yellow;
}

#el{
position:fixed;
top:14px;
left:14px;
right:14px;
bottom:14px;

-webkit-transition: all 7s;
-moz-transition: all 7s;
-o-transition: all 7s;
transition: all 7s;


}

#el.changeState{
-webkit-backdrop-filter:blur(7px);
backdrop-filter:blur(7px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<button onclick="Clicked()">Blur Me (:</button>
<script>
function Clicked() {
  var el = document.getElementById('el');
  
  el.innerHTML = ":O";
  el.classList.add('changeState');
}
</script>

<p id="el"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

What would be much much better:

```js
(function addBlurEffect() {

  const d = document;

  function getId(id) {
    return d.getElementById(id);
  }

  let emptyParagaphTag = getId(`addTextTo`);
  let button = getId(`listeningToButton`);

  
  button.addEventListener(`click`, function stateClicked() {
      this.innerHTML = `:O`;
      emptyParagaphTag.classList.add(`changeState`);

      // No overflows ;)
      button.removeEventListener(`click`, stateClicked);
  });
})();

// In my opinion, this Javascript code is much cleaner!
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d2/64/ce/d264ce996ff6531fe191dfce5b200b3a.jpg");
  background-position: center; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: yellow; /* This wouldn't work... since it wold be covered.. I don't understand what you want with that, other than getting blinded? */
}

#addTextTo {
  position:fixed;
  top:14px;
  left:14px;
  right:14px;
  bottom:14px;

  -webkit-transition: all 7s;
  -moz-transition: all 7s;
  -o-transition: all 7s;
  transition: all 7s;
  
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); /* You forgot to add this! */
}

.changeState {
  filter: blur(7px); /* Much better! */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- HTML code is free to breath now, nothing to be clogged here. -->
<button id="listeningToButton">Blur Me (:</button>
<p id="addTextTo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

## Outro.

Hopefully, I've helped you achieve what you want and cleared all the confusion... also, I am open to any questions about anything in the code.

## Links.

(*) = Links for things!

W3C => https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#supported-filter-functions

CanIUse `backdrop-filter` (bad) rule => https://caniuse.com/#search=backdrop%20filter

CanIUse `filter` (good) rule => https://caniuse.com/#search=CSS%20Filter%20Effects

Comment: **Thanks** for your detailed answer ❤️, but i can't mark it as an answer. i knew about the [support tables](https://caniuse.com/#search=backdrop%20filter).But, what i was really trying to achieve, was that exact kind of effect, a blurry-glassy transition in the background of an element without that "inset Shadow"  , thats why i used ```backdrop-filter``` and not ```filter```, even if generally is not recomened [...]

Comment: *```In my opinion, this Javascript code is much cleaner!```* i agree (:

Comment: *```actually, this is how backdrop-filter style-rule works according to W3C```* Nice! i didn't know that..

Comment: ```background-color:yellow;``` used for visual reasons, **in case image desapeare in future**

Comment: Well sadly, you can't do that, as the transition makes up for more of a problem, if you remove the transition and the background-colour, it would work fine (with or without the background colour).

Comment: ` used for visual reasons, in case image desapeare in future`
Good redundant engineering tactic, I applaud you for your critical thinking ability!

Comment: *```Good redundant engineering tactic, I applaud you for your critical thinking ability! ```* ❤️