# Transition on backdrop-filter blur causing dark inset borders (in chrome AND windows only)

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-filters

**Edit: As of chrome version: 119.0.6045.200, this seems to have been resolved in chrome itseld**

During a transition on backdrop-filter, I'm noticing a dark inset shadow, only visible *during* the transition.

It seems this only happens in **chrome/webkit** based browsers on **windows** (10 & 11) :
My current chrome version is: 'Version 116.0.5845.190 (Official Build) (64-bit)'

It also seems that this *does* happen in stackoverflows inline 'run code snippet'
But **not**  for stackoverflows code snippet editor
In my actual project I'm also seeing these inset borders.

I would like to get rid of the inset borders.
**Is this an issue with the code or unintended/undefined behavior on the browsers part?**

### Examples

Chrome with issue:
[image: chrome with visual issue]
And Firefox seems fine:
[image]

#### Example code:

Clicking this button in chrome will show these black inset borders;
Though within stackoverflow snippet editor, the borders are not visible.
In this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hp78uL40/) the behavior can also be observed.

```js
function toggle() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("inner")[0].classList.toggle('blurred')
}
```

```css
.inner {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: backdrop-filter 500ms;
}

.blurred {
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 20%;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #57cdff, #05a915);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">toggle backdrop-filter: blur(5px)</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    Hello!
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not seeing the issue on your JSFiddle on Chrome on OSX, are you on Windows?

Comment: Thanks @dan, the plot thickens .  Yes, this is indeed on windows. I tried a Windows 10 Box and a windows 11 Box. Both seem to misbehave.  Tried this on Android Phone  as well (Chrome and FF) and that's behaving fine, no issues. I'll update the question to reflect these findings.  Though i think's it's safe to say this a bugged behavior on windows only and not with the code itself.

Comment: Got onto a Windows 11 machine and now I'm seeing the same thing, there was a [question posed back in 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62507715/backdrop-blur-effect-creates-inset-shadow-issue-during-transition) that had the same issue but apparently said the issue was resolved in Chrome 91, I'm wondering if whatever fix Google applied got broken in a recent version of Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `opacity` of an element that already has a `backdrop-filter`.
Changed your code a bit in the example:

```js
button.onclick = () =>  document.querySelector('.text').classList.toggle('blurred');
```

```css
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #57cdff, #05a915);
  padding: 20px;
}

.text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  min-height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.text:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  transition: opacity .5s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.text.blurred:after {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">toggle backdrop-filter: blur(5px)</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing the same issue and here are my findings:

- It is not a matter of Windows or Windows 10 vs Windows 11. It is about whether Chrome is using "Use hardware acceleration when available" or not.
- URL for this Chrome setting: chrome://settings/system
- HW acceleration **on**: You get the shadow inset bug during transition, which then disappears once the transition is complete.
- HW acceleration **off**: The image doesn't get blurred from the edges.
- Firefox has no issues.

Whether Chrome 91 fixed this issue two years ago and it has since returned, I can't say. My fix for right now was what imhvost suggested, which is to have the backdrop-filter blur effect on its own div always, and simply transition the opacity of that div from 0 to 1. It's not ideal, but it gets the job done for now while I wait and hope they fix the behavior.

Comment: The lack of edge-blurring on Chrome appears to have returned. Currently seeing the problem using Version 123.0.6312.59 (Official Build) (64-bit), when only a few days previous there was no issue. Occurs whether hardware acceleration (now called "Use graphics acceleration when available") is on or off.